# Problema con iteración para submuestra en R

Tags: r, bucles

Cómo están? Es mi primera consulta por aquí así que desde ya gracias!

Estoy intentando realizar una muestra aleatoria de un DF. En el mismo tengo 286 filas, y para cada DEPARTAMENTO (28 DEPARTAMENTO únicos) tengo que extraer una muestra según mi columna mh. La suma de los valores de mi columna mh por departamento da un total de 250. Por lo que debería tener una muestra de 250 filas, pero respetando los tamaños de muestra según mh por departamento. Escribí este código y una función que itere para hacerlo.

Sin embargo, por algún motivo, me devuelve una muestra de 248! Y no sé a qué se debe. Copio todo:

```
library(SamplingUtil)

urlfile = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oblitterator/tecnicas_muestreo/main/segunda_muestra.csv'

segunda_muestra =  read_csv(url(urlfile))

conglomerados = unique(segunda_muestra$DEPARTAMENTO)
sample<- list()
idcolnum <- which(colnames(segunda_muestra)=="CUIE")

for(i in 1:length(conglomerados)){
  
  subsample<-data.frame(segunda_muestra[which(segunda_muestra$DEPARTAMENTO==conglomerados[i]),])
  
  sample[[i]]<-sys.sample(nrow(subsample), as.numeric(unique(subset(segunda_muestra, DEPARTAMENTO == conglomerados[i])[13])))

 sample[[i]]<-subsample[unlist(sample[[i]]),idcolnum]
 }

#Genera el data frame de ids seleccionados(ya que estaban en una lista)
sampledf<-data.frame(id=unlist(sample))

#Uniendo el data frame de datos con la muestra seleccionada mendiante la llave creada

muestrappt <-inner_join(unique(sampledf),
                        unique(segunda_muestra),
                        by = c("id" ="CUIE"))

muestrappt
```

Comment: Bienvenido Juan Nieve. Estoy tratando de reproducir tu código y no encuentro la función `sys.sample()`. ¿Pertenece a una librería? ¿La desarrollaste tú mismo?

Comment: No termino de entender lo que estás haciendo, pero quizás el problema sea que en La Matanza y en Luján hay CUIE repetidos. Con tidyverse prueba `segunda_muestra %>% count(DEPARTAMENTO, CUIE, sort = T)`. Seguramente algún `unique` los elimine en el camino y por eso obtienes 248 o 249 al final. Pude reproducir el código reemplazando la función `sys.sample()` por `sample()`, por favor mira mi comentario anterior.

Comment: Hola!! Muchísimas gracias por responder!!!! sys.sample() pertenece a la librería SamplingUtil. Ahí lo edito arriba!! Voy a probar lo que me comentás, gracias!!

Comment: Ahí revisé, era exactamente eso, un problema de datos, estaba duplicado el CUIE. Debería haber revisado eso en primer lugar! Muchísimas gracias!!!

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvió. Adapté el comentario a respuesta, si consideras que responde tu pregunta puedes darla por aceptada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me termina de quedar claro que es lo que es lo que buscas, pero como están los datos y el código pude replicarlo y creo que encontré el problema.

En los partidos de La Matanza y en Luján hay valores de CUIE repetidos. Como `n` es casi tan grande como `N` casi siempre quedan en la remuestra y alguno de los `unique()` los eliminan.

Puedes verificarlo con:

```
library(tidyverse)
segunda_muestra %>% count(DEPARTAMENTO, CUIE, sort = T)
```